# functional second derivative

Tags: constrained-optimization, variational-calculus

I'm trying to build a numerical solution for a parameter estimation problem of reaction-diffusion equation, using the adjoint method.

To summarize it, I'm trying to minimize the function 
$$ G=\frac{1}{2}\int_\Omega{(u(T,x)-u_f)^2d\Omega} + \frac{1}{2}\int_\Omega{D^2d\Omega}+ \frac{1}{2}\int_\Omega{k^2d\Omega} $$

subject to

\begin{align}
F = \partial_t u - \nabla(D\nabla u) - ku(1-u) = 0 \\
u(0,x) = u_0 \\
u(t,x) = 0 ~\forall x\in\Gamma :=\partial\Omega
\end{align}

where $u$ is the tumor density function, $\Omega$ is the space domain of the problem and $D$, $k$ are the unknown diffusion and proliferation terms (to optimize in order to find the minimal $G$).

Thank to [GoHookie's help](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/28468/25963), I have now a proper derivation of the Lagrangian
$$ L = G - \lambda F $$ giving me an expression of the total derivative of $G$ w.r.t the unknown parameters $D$ and $k$

$$
\frac{\partial L}{\partial D}(\delta D) = \int_\Omega\int_t^T{(\frac{D}{T}-\nabla \lambda\nabla u)\delta Dd\Omega dt} \\
\frac{\partial L}{\partial k}(\delta k) = \int_\Omega\int_t^T{(\frac{k}{T}-\lambda u(1-u))\delta k d\Omega dt}
$$

Since the problem is non-linear, I have to use an iterative optimization methods, which requires me also to provide an expression of the Hessian of $G$.

Using again an adjoint method, leads to calculate the various second derivatives of $L$ w.r.t $u, D$ and $k$.

I think I can manage it except for the case of
$$ \frac{\partial^2 L}{\partial u\partial D}(\delta u,\delta D) = -\int_\Omega\int_t^T{(\nabla \lambda\nabla \delta u)\delta Dd\Omega dt} $$

since then, I think I need to factorize this expression both for $\delta u$ and $\delta D$ (i.e. transform the expression in something like $\int_\Omega\int_0^T{\left( J(u,\lambda,\nabla u,\nabla \lambda)\delta u\delta \lambda\right) d\Omega dt}$ ) but none of the divergence theorem, Green theorem or integration by part methods seems to help me doing this factorization.

Any help ?

Thx

Comment: there was an error in my initial derivation of the gradient equations. you should see the updated answer for the correct formulation of $\partial L/\partial k$ and $\partial L / \partial D$.

Comment: The expression for the second derivative in question looks correct to me. But I don't understand what you mean by "I think I need to factorize this expression". Can you explain what you mean by that?

Comment: I guess, if I want to have a usable expression, it need to be transformed into something like $ \int_\Omega \int_t^T{(J(u,\lambda,\nabla u,\nabla \lambda))\delta u  \delta D d\Omega dt } $ I mean the $\delta D$ and $\delta u$  should not appears inside the gradient .. isn't it right ?

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth, I've just edited the question to precise my concern.

Comment: @davidguez You're guessing wrong; this is exactly what you get. What you *do* with it is another question -- in general, you can't get an explicit Hessian, you can only use this to compute the action of the Hessian in a direction $\delta D$. Luckily, this is all you need for a Krylov method such as CG, which allows you to iteratively solve the Newton step (approximately). The keyword to Google is *Newton--Krylov* (or *Krylov--Newton*) method.

Comment: Indeed -- one of the two functions $\delta u,\delta D$ is going to be your Newton update, the other a test function for the variational equation that defines this update.

Comment: @davidguez for large-scale problems, Gâteaux second derivatives (Hessian-vector products) come at a [significant computational cost](https://arxiv.org/abs/1601.06609). You'll want to check if this overhead pays off in terms of solution accuracy / convergence speed. if it does not, I suggest you look into an alternative method that uses only first-order derivative information, such as Gauss-Newton or BFGS.

Comment: @GoHokies, actually I tried using L-BFGS (since the hessian estimation does not fit in memory) but the code does not converges so I thought to try using an explicit Hessian expression... but maybe just have to debug my code and L-BFGS will actually works...

Comment: @ChristianClason, thanks for the info... I thought it was mandatory  to do this "factorization" because basically I'd like to use fminunc from matlab which requires me to provide an hessian matrix, so I thought that this matrix is formed, for each element, by replacing $\delta u$ by a kronecker symbol (1 in  the relevant cell 0 elsewhere, something like a dirac thus). With this in mind I'm afraid of using $\nabla \delta u$ in my calculation. I'll check the Newton-Krylov method but do you mean that I'll have to use some kind of gradient of a dirac like function to calculate the Hessian ?

Comment: @davidguez To build a full matrix, you indeed insert every basis vector into this expression. Which basis vector depends on your discretization -- for linear finite elements, the basis vectors are hat functions centered on each node, whose gradient is well-defined. Note that $\delta u$ is the variation in $u$ and hence lies in the same space -- so if $\nabla u$ makes sense in your original PDE, so does $\nabla \delta u$.

Comment: And `fminunc` will happily take a function that returns the action of the Hessian on a provided vector in place of a full matrix; see https://mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/writing-scalar-objective-functions.html#bsj1e55. This is by far the better option unless the problem size is really small.

Comment: @ChristianClason, I agree that $\delta u$ lies in the same space as $u$ but the reason why I'm more afraid of using calculation with $\nabla \delta u$ than on $\nabla u$ is that $u$ is typically smooth while $\delta u$ will have sharp spatial variations (0 to 1 in 1 pixel width) and I thought this may lead to numerical instabilities. But anyway I'll try and hope this will help (using a matrix-vector product as advised). Thank you